# B2C Logout not calling a SAML IdP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a B2C successfully logging in to a B2C. B2C is configured to use a SAML IdP, which it does on login. However, a logout message to B2C results in B2C calling back to the application's logout url but not to the SAML IdP. The user thus effectively stays signed to the IdP and is never re-challenged on new logins to the B2C. Is there something that needs to be setup in the policy for that?

Comment: Look at this answer  4
down vote

Azure AD B2C does not support signing you out from the external identity provider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382106/azure-ad-b2c-openid-connect-single-logout-with-ws-federation-and-saml-claims-pro

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience, single sign-out is only supported by Azure AD B2C for the Microsoft Account identity provider (where the identity provider session is ended using a hidden iframe), not for any other identity providers.